# How to merge columns/cells datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've been trying to merge columns in a datagridview after I add some values the way I want, yet sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I can try this if you add 2 datagridviews, one with 6 columns and the other with 1 column.

I'm using extra cells to "store" some values and then delete them .

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        For j = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If i > j Then
                'If DataGridView1(0, i).Value = DataGridView1(0, j).Value Then
                If DataGridView1(0, i).Value = DataGridView1(0, j).Value Then
                    DataGridView1(3, i).Value = DataGridView1(1, i).Value + DataGridView1(1, j).Value
                End If
            End If
            If i < j Then
                'If DataGridView1(0, i).Value = DataGridView1(0, j).Value Then
                If DataGridView1(0, i).Value = DataGridView1(0, j).Value Then
                    DataGridView1(4, i).Value = DataGridView1(1, i).Value + DataGridView1(1, j).Value
                End If
            End If
            If i = j Then
                DataGridView1(5, i).Value = DataGridView1(1, i).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Call lezgo()
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub lezgo()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
    Next
    If i > 0 Then
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(i)
    End If
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        DataGridView2(0, i).Value = DataGridView1(3, i).Value + DataGridView1(4, i).Value + DataGridView1(5, i).Value
         Next

    DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(Column4)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(Column5)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Remove(Column6)
End Sub
```

I know it's really bad what I'm doing, but it kinda worked. But now I want to optimize this, and I can't figure this out..

When I'm not able to do this, it shows the error "System.InvalidCastException" . 
I've googled a bit and I see no similar project.. Tks!

EDIT:

```
1| A| one
2| B| two
3| A| three
2| C| four
1| D| five
4| B| six
```

i want to->

```
1| A| one      |AD  |   |  |               |AD       this is dgv2
2| B| two      |BC  |CE |  |               |BCE
3| A| three    |    |   |A |               |A
2| C| four     |BC  |CE |  |               |BCE
1| D| five     |AD  |   |  |               |AD
4| B| six      |    |   |B |               |B
2| E| seven    |BC  |CE |  |               |BCE
```

Comment: Show us your data (from the 2 datagridviews) and describe what exactly it is you want to achieve (possibly with an example)

Comment: updated the question :)

Comment: So, the data in the 4th column is dynamically created from the letters in the second column according to the occurrences of the number in the first column for each row... OK, give me 30 mins and I'll post an answer....

Comment: i want it to be like that .. but at this moment i can only do it if i add 3 more columns,1 to store when i > j, other to i <j and another when i=j . You can see that on the code i've posted

Comment: With all due respect, that's not the way I would do it. And I don't want to have to go though your code to figure it out.... your new comments\edits give others a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve so maybe they will contribute a solution...

Comment: ye i know it is not legit, that's why i need an optimization. and i don't mind to change the whole code, i just don't know how to go the whole way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim folder = "Path to your CSV folder (do not include the file name here)"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ' change Test.csv to your csv file name here
    Try
        Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [csv.csv]", CnStr)
            Adp.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    dt.Columns.Add("New Data", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    For Each DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
        ' Get the data for new column
        Dim query = From r In dt.AsEnumerable() Where r.Field(Of Integer)("F1") = DataRow("F1") Select r.Field(Of String)("F2")
        ' Join it together ad put it in the DataTable
        DataRow("New Data") = String.Join("", query)
    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

Store your 3 columns of data data in a file called 'csv.csv'. and remember to set the path to the folder of the csv file in the code above (at the Dim folder = .....) you need to have the data in the format like below...

```
1, A, one
2, B, two
3, A, three
2, C, four
1, D, five
4, B, six
2, E, seven
```

I tried using the '|' but don't have the time right now to get that working, so i used a ',' to seperate the values in the csv file

Anyway, when you run the code, the 4th column is filled dynamically with the correct codes.... Hope that helps.....

you can also use the same logic to update the 4th column as you manually enter new rows\data directly into the DataGridView1 control in the DataGridView1_CellEndEdit event....

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit

    For Each DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
        ' Get the data for new column
        Dim query = From r In dt.AsEnumerable() Where r.Field(Of Integer)("F1") = DataRow("F1") Select r.Field(Of String)("F2")
        ' Join it together ad put it in the DataTable
        DataRow("New Data") = String.Join("", query)
        'dt.Rows(1)("New Data") = String.Join("", query)
    Next

End Sub
```

you will also have to move the declaration for the DataTable to the top of the Form Class like so....

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dt As New DataTable
```

Comment: i did everything as u told me, but it shows the error "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" , something like the conversion is not valid @`Where r.Field(Of Integer)("F1") = DataRow("F1")`

Comment: Make sure that the data is stored exactly as I have it above, also make sure that you are only adding one new column ("New Data") .  It sounds like a local problem and I cannot see your code  (maybe update your question).

Comment: Also, if you are manually entering data into the DataGridView using the keyboard then the first column HAS to be a number....

Comment: i had it in diferrent columns. sorry ! ye it works fine the way you did. i'll try to adapt the code and go the whole way around. thank you!